# Trying to have autocomplete enabled for a sheet in Numbers on macOS that is pulling the names from a list on a second worksheet

Tags: macos, iwork-numbers, page-numbers

I have a list of roughly 150 names in a single column on a worksheet in Numbers. I run a weekly report that needs to include some of the names and omit others. My goal is to have the weekly worksheet autocomplete the names for me as I begin typing to speed up the workflow. I am running Numbers on a 2023 MacBook Pro with an M3 Pro chip, macOS version is 14.1.2. Any support would be appreciated.